# can not convert type string to Bool

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to convert First Element in to String in the try block?

I have tried to convert ToString() as well. That is also throwing error.

```
foreach (var column in elementIndex)
{
    try
    {
        columnHeaders[index] = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#columntable" + table.TableID + " > div:nth-child(" + column + ")")).First(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text);                       
    }
    catch
    {
        columnHeaders[index] = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='columntablegrid']/div[" + column + "]/div/div")).Text;
    }                    
    index++;
}
```

Comment: what error is it raising ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`First()` needs `bool` parameter but you are giving it `string`. You need to add condition

```
First(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text.equals(parameterToCompare));
```

> can not convert type string to Bool

Means that you already have `string` when `bool` is expected, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is here

`First(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text);`

you need something like this

`First(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text == "your condition to bring back the first element");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition in your `First` clause:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#columntable" + table.TableID + " > div:nth-child(" + column + ")"))
      .First(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text == "condition");
```